# How can I get my own playerID when it is not my turn?

Tags: android, google-play-services

How do I get my playerID (or ParticipantId) when it is not my turn (e.g. getCurrentPlayerID() does not work)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, getCurrentPlayerId actually works. I use it like this:

```
String ownPlayerId = Games.Players.getCurrentPlayerId(mGoogleApiClient);
```

*Current in this context means the player currently signed in on the device, not the player currently having turn.*

You only have one player ID, but your participant ID may differ in different TurnBasedMatch'es. To get your own participant ID for a specific match, use:

```
String ownParticipantId = mMatch.getParticipantId(ownPlayerId);
```

Comment: Great! Thanks! your answer got me thinking and I rewrote the whole function. Works great now! =)